# How to get date and month from a input - PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, bootstrap-5

How to get only date and month from a input not year - PHP

```
<input  type="month" class="form-control" id="f_start_date" name="f_start_date"  />
```

getting as

[image]

expected as **2 November** in input box

Answer (score 0):

We first get the value of the input field using the `$_POST` variable. We then create a new `DateTime` object from the input value.

Next, we use the `format()` method of the `DateTime` object to extract the month and day in the format of m and d, respectively.

```
// Get the value of the input field
$inputValue = $_POST['f_start_date'];

// Parse the input value into a date object
$date = new DateTime($inputValue);

// Extract the month and day from the date object
$month = $date->format('m');
$day = $date->format('d');
```

Comment: how can see in input

Comment: @ShivendraKr.Sahu as of my research, the type="date" input field does not allow customization of the display format using CSS or Bootstrap. The format of the displayed date is determined by the user's browser settings and cannot be changed.